# Using chart.js with laravel passing data from controller to view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent, chart.js

Trying to utilize chart.js in my laravel app. In my controller, I'm using Eloquent to perform a simple query of the database:

### `//sampleController.php`

```
public function test()
{
  $inventories = Inventory::all();
  $dates = $inventories->lists('updated_at');
  $totals = $inventories->lists('item_4801');

  return view('pages.test')
      ->with('dates')
      ->with('totals');
}
```

I'm passing 'dates' and 'totals' to my view:

### `//test.blade.php`

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
@stop

@section('footer')
  <script src="assets/admin/js/Chart.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var data = {
        labels: {!! json_encode($dates) !!},
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My Data",                    
                data: {!! json_encode($totals) !!}
            }
        ]
    };
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
  </script>
@stop
```

This doesn't work. The chart placeholder shows but it seems the data is being read as null. I'm guessing I'm just not passing the data in the correct format, but not sure exactly how I would do that. I can confirm that the data is being passed from controller to view, as I can dump the variable and see the data. Evidently it's just not in a format that chartjs can understand.
Any information would be greatly appreciated. Just a nudge in the right direction would help.
Many thanks,
Clay

Comment: would you be able to post the script block in the browser? (view source)

Comment: Absolutely. I'll get that posted shortly. Basically, my issue is probably independent of chartjs. I just need to know how to take my "dates" and "totals" variables and make a basic flat array of that information. Really standard stuff, but I just can't make it happen...so frustrated.

Comment: Ok, got this figured out. Will post answer shortly so maybe it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was the 'dates' variable causing the problem (in addition to a syntax error). Chartjs was looking for an array like:
    `["2015/06/08", 2015/06/13", "2015/6/20"]`
instead of the collection object from the eloquent query.
So I ran `$dates = array_column($inventories->toArray(), 'updated_at');` to get the array, then reformatted the dates by running:

```
foreach ($dates as $date){
    $formatted_dates[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
}
```

Then I passed `$formatted_dates` to the view.
I'm sure there's a better way, but I'm learning more everyday and it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

In your model;

use this

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return  date('m/d/Y', strtotime($value));
}
```